# embed a framework in bundle and link it

Tags: xcode, macos, frameworks

I have a MacOS app and I added a framework (let's call it `A.framework`, which is a folder) in "embedded binaries", which also shows up in "Linked Frameworks and libraries". The project compiles and runs fine.

But when I copy the app bundle to another MacBook, it does not run and tells me it cannot find a second framework (let's call it `B.framework`) to load. `A.framework` links to `B.framework` with an absolute path, so even if I change the install name for `A.framework`, it still looks for `B.framework` using the absolute path. Is there a way for me to change this in `A.framework`? I don't have the source code for the `A.framework`.

I used `otool` tool on the binary and find out it is NOT linking the framework within the bundle (the bundle has a copy of the framework embedded in the bundle). The linker still points to where the framework was copied as set via an "embedded binaries" path, which is an absolute path on my development machine.

How do I make it point to the `B.framework` inside the bundle?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to better explain how you copied your app bundle and how you are building your app bundle. Without knowing this, it is hard to help you.

Comment: I find out - one framework (A) links to another framework (B) with an absolute path. so even I change the install name for A, it still look a framework B using the absolute path. Is there way I can change this in framework A ? I don't have the source code for framework A.

Comment: how do I make this as an accepted answer? Many thanks to Jvarela!

Comment: I will transfer the comment to a formal answer, but I think you should edit your question with the comment that clarified your problem, so that others with the same problem can benefit from it.

Comment: I edited your question to make it clearer. Let's see if my edit is approved. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `install_tool_path` in your developer tools and apply the `-change` flag to `A.framework`, but I am not sure if that is not going to break the code signing of that framework. Anyway, read doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/osx-deployment.html. They show how to use this tool to change paths in bundles.